# Determine whether a binary number is of power of two in verilog code

Tags: verilog, fpga, one-hot-encoding

I am trying to determine whether a binary number is of power of two (in other words, is it of one-hot encoding).

I found a [method](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#DetermineIfPowerOf2) to do so, but it is for integer.

Could anyone help to transform the method for usage with binary number in verilog ?

[image]

Comment: Think about this: how is an integer stored?

Comment: @Oldfart I have also thought the same thing just like you had just now. However, when you try to implement the code in verilog and pass the code into verilator for linting purpose, you will understand why I am posting this question.

Comment: What does Verilator complain about then? It may be wrong, or it may not like you to using 'int' and wants 'integer'.

Comment: Think about binary bits.  What if _v_ is of 8 bits ? What do _!_ and_&_ do ? Should _f_ be only 1 bit in this case ?

Comment: Post what you have tried, and the errors you get.

Comment: @dave_59 See the [verilator linting output](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/bNmf97dScf/) with [is_power_of_two.v](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/BNKv7NwVSS/)

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your code—it's limitations of the tool you are using. 
Verilator requires code with inputs and outputs so it can be stimulated and results displayed. 
It also doesn't like performing logical operators on multi-bit operands.

```
module is_power_of_two(output reg f);

reg [7:0];
initial begin
   #1 v = 8'b11110000;
   #1;
end

always @(*) f = v != 0 && !((v & v - 1) != 0);

endmodule
```

Comment: @Oldfart Someone suggested me to use power_of_two = ^v which is so much simpler. Any comment ?

Comment: @kevin, reduction xor will check the set bits count parity, not the power of two property. Say, for both numbers 4 and 7 reduction xor will report true, but 7 is not the power of two.

Comment: ok, by the way, `always @(*) f = |v & (&(v & v - 1));` also works well

Comment: Reduction or `|v` is logically identical to inequality to 0 `v!=0`